# ECharts tree: how to draw a horizontal split line in the middle of the tree

Tags: javascript, tree, line, echarts

How to have a split line from the tree's left to the right edge, like the below one using ECharts:
[image]

Currently, the below HTML and JavaScript code could generate the tree without the split line, but not sure how to add a split line for the tree, similar to the tree's curved lines.
HTML file *tree.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/echarts@5.4.3/dist/echarts.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="tree" style="width: 800px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <script src="tree.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file *tree.js*:

```
// Create an ECharts instance
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('tree'));

var dogData = {
    name: 'Dog A',
    children: [
        {
            name: 'Sire',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'Sire Sire',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Sire Dam',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            name: 'Dam',
            children: [
                {
                    name: 'Dam Sire',
                },
                {
                    name: 'Dam Dam',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
};

// Create the tree structure
var treeOption = {
    series: [
        {
            type: 'tree',
            roam: true,
            layout: 'horizontal',
            data: [dogData],
            symbol: 'emptyCircle',
            symbolSize: 7,
            initialTreeDepth: -1,
            animationDurationUpdate: 750,
            label: {
                position: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'middle',
                align: 'left',
                fontSize: 9
            },
            leaves: {
                label: {
                  position: 'left',
                  verticalAlign: 'middle',
                  align: 'right'
                }
            },
        },
    ],
};

// Set option and render the chart
myChart.setOption(treeOption);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Heres](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=tree-basic&code=LYTwwgFghgTgLgOgM4QPYHcAyqoBMCWAdgOYAUAlANwBQAJAsQKZykBKA8uwCoD6ACgEEuACQAEAalEByAPS4ocKDKhIkzOQqUAzADaxGCAFZJUhKQBpRWgK6EAxnHynRpeYvKiA3tVGjQkWEQIfFxGbDwiMiofUTcoBDtgnVwYRkIELVQYAFEoRNIbe0dnVwVrYEsiUIAPD29fXyrGatEAUlEAJlEAXl7RAAZRADIhlzdyhNQdPQAHNVwe0TgYa0Zo3wBfdb9waHhkZnYZ4sJSGN9SVGOnQkX6ht84VCnHGYAuL3OHpZh8YiYYB8pPg4IxgBYvg9ln8AexCEDgKhrGpEQA3RhSSGiDbmLFqX6MJAfADaWN892-DTgIBmjCBy0YGNxlIecRJcQAusyWY8rkCAIytCE83w6RhaOBAgDsQu5PIARqg4E9gALZWSGr9iBBJdIOv11SLREgQMBFToAMr4ABedNEUrlLL08sYOg-FJFM1QSBBNyBYolwqNonR8HwdigOgEOj-8OkwBCuDFQaNkdjQK1OpTIsyhDgVttHwAnBrNo7KWKoOiiZ9g6Jna73aXvl6fScM38s-WRaHHBGozHiHGpAncEmmc2Hmmh_7xXBMXWNs2cc2wTNoD6ax6eZk7MigaEkHY0vI8wuRSujc0ZlBCLgBHewFNZmoPstVt2p4R8MAFDcACLWDAf6mB8ACsYH9J-DS3j-IGEIBwEnAAqjMbh2lKkEapeLLbt81K0kCxDAeu2aUj6Yp5m-KyMNBjSgsAFrUmK7p2FMWT0reSA3qkZ44TybKiMSnjVB8UEgGJGxcs2v4wAA1pgRB2nhlKCcSwlsVkuAkgAtPyCBgeY_QcjiniaTA2lCfphnGVJ0l1iaZpTCSUiEKYTLSG5hAYvZwYxt5TEgCxtZ1qIbE6Bx0jyjoqznkaS7xdBCXfByXxbDE0RbJQQA) a hacky solution: You can add a graph series, make it transparent and use the `markLine` property to specify coordinates (the series seems to have at minimum one node for the markLine to appear).

A drawback would be that the line is bound to its coordinates and wont move according to the tree if its collapsed / extended.

Code:

```js
series: [
    ...,
    {
        type: 'graph',
        silent: true,
        itemStyle: {color: 'tansparent'},
        data: [{x: 0,y: 0}],
        markLine: {
            data: [[{coord: [-1.5,0]},{coord: [1.5,0]}]],
            symbol: ['none', 'none'],
            lineStyle: {
                color: 'blue'
            }
        },
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, when zoom in/out or move the tree around on the canvas, the markLine doesn't follow the tree's changes, so this solution is not good enough

Comment: @J.W You could maybe try to experiment with [rich text labels](https://echarts.apache.org/en/tutorial.html#Rich%20Text) to achieve something